# Twilio Video start recording manually

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video, twilio-javascript

I'm working on a video call web application using Twilio Video REST API and JavaScript SDK 2.8.0.

My requirement is that Users should be able to record video calls only if they want to record, and there is no need to record all calls automatically.

According to twilio documentation, group video rooms created via the REST API can specify whether to record or not in the initial room creation HTTP POST request only. (using RecordParticipantsOnConnect=True)

Is there any possibility to start recording after room was created ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently no. You would have to move participants to another room to record them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is it possible to achieve this without disconnecting the video stream ?